# How to fix binary operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, compiler-errors, declaration

Error C2676 binary '[': 'collection::item' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I read few posts and Microsoft VS site, but cannot understand how to fix the problem

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class collection {
private:
    class item {
    public:
        T1 item; T2 key;
    };
    unsigned int top;
    item array = new item[top];
public:
    collection& operator[](unsigned int i) {
        return array[i];
    }
    collection(int top) {
        this->top = top;
    }
    void coutarr() {
        for (int i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) {
            cout << array[i].item << endl;
        }
    }
    void extendarray() {
        item x = new item[top*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            x[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete []array;
        swap(array, x);
        top = top*2;

    }
    void addvar(int i, T1 item, T2 key) {
        array[i].item = item; array[i].key = key; //Here 2 Errors
    }
};
```

If someone can explain what shall I do, I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell with this little information but I'd assume that your `item` class does not provide an implementation for `operator=` (or copy constructor).
Can you show your `item` class?

Comment: @JoelBodenmann _item_ is a nested class, `class item {
    public:
        T1 item; T2 key;
    };`

Comment: @Keanu This declaration item array = new item[top]; is invalid.

Comment: Just a guess: top has no value. That makes is an array with zero length at best (which is really bad) and undefined behavior at worst.

Comment: I'm guessing that `item array = new item[top];` should be a pointer: `item *array = new item[top];`

Answer (score 2):

> Error C2676 binary '[': 'collection::item' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

this is because

> ```
> item array = new item[top];
> ```

must be

```
item * array = new item[top];
```

but you also have to move the initialization in the constructor when *top* has a value

---

Out of that is was better that the constructor `collection(int top)` get an unsigned value being `collection(unsigned top)` or better `collection(size_t top)`

Copy contructor, operator= ... are missing while an attribute is a pointer

What about to check the validity of *i* in `collection& operator[](unsigned int i)` and `void addvar(int i, T1 item, T2 key)` to produce an exception when it is invalid ? *addvar* is also a strange name because it is a *set*, a *add* means the size is increased. You cannot access to an element on a const instance, add `const collection& operator[](unsigned int i) const`

In `void extendarray()` to double the size will not do a lot if the initial size is 0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: `top` is unititialized. That makes array an array with zero length at best (which is really bad) and invokes undefined behavior at worst.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean at least something like the following

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class collection {
private:
    class item {
    public:
        T1 item; T2 key;
    };
    unsigned int top;
    item *array;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
public:
    auto & operator[](unsigned int i) {
    ^^^^
        return array[i];
    }

    collection(unsigned int top) : top( top ), array( new item[top]{} )
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
    }

    ~collection() { delete []array; }
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    collection( const collection & ) = delete;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    collection & operator =( const collection & ) = delete;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

    void coutarr() {
        for (int i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) {
            cout << array[i].item << endl;
        }
    }
    void extendarray() {
        item x = new item[top*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            x[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete []array;
        swap(array, x);
        top = top*2;

    }
    void addvar(int i, const T1 &item, const T2 &key) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        array[i].item = item; array[i].key = key; //Here 2 Errors
    }
};
```

Of course you can futher develop the code.